# Why does the maven-compiler-plugin omit the context of a compilation error?

Tags: java, maven

I'm compiling a faulty Java class like this:

```
public class App {
    private final String name;
}
```

When calling the Java compiler directly, I'm getting the following error, including the context of the error:

```
integration-test/src/main/java/com/example/foo/App.java:11: error: variable name not initialized in the default constructor
private final String name;
                     ^
```

Now, when compiling the same class through Maven, the contextual informatin (faulty source code line and the "^" marker indicating the erroneous element) is missing:

```
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.0:compile (default-compile) @ integration-test ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 3 source files to integration-test/target/classes
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR :
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] integration-test/src/main/java/com/example/foo/App.java:[11,25] error: variable name not initialized in the default constructor
[INFO] 1 error
```

Is there a way to show the contextual information in this case, too? Or is this an intentional design of the Maven compiler plug-in (or *plexus-compiler-javac*, more specifically)?

Comment: You could try `mvn -X`

Comment: Or, less verbose, `mvn -e` to just print the full trace on errors.

Comment: The maven output includes the column number. Are you sure you're running the same javac version in both cases? Try `mvn -v` to verify.

Comment: Neither -X nor -e help. Interestingly, though, I do see the context when setting the `fork` option of the compiler plug-in to false. I tend to think that's a bug in the plug-in's processing of the output by the external javac processing when `fork` is true.